# Can we add user into group by editing group file in /etc folder

Tags: linux

I would like to add a user(sachin) into a group(mqm). I would like add user by editing group file. Is it okay to add user name by editing group file like below

```
mqm:x:1000:clasic,gtcj,fgmmin,fddmin,sachin
```

when i fire command `groups sachin` i am getting output like below.

```
sachin : unix-sachin-g mqm
```

So adding user id sachin into mqm group is done ?

Comment: I'd recommend you use something like `usermod(8)`. Safer than messing with system files by hand.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim :Yes i understand, but i have already done this. So I just want to confirm if it works or not. Is it added or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's ok to add user to /etc/group directly, but the common way is to use something like usermod:

```
sudo usermod -a -G mqm sachin
```

Note, group membership changes do not take effect for current user login sessions, requiring the user to reconnect to be affected by the changes.

Comment: How to add if user is not there on that server?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? The usermod and similar operates only on local passwd and group files, so the user should exist on this server, and if authentication is provided through, for example, LDAP, then groups should be configured there.